# What happens if I write touches event for a View in its View Controller?

Tags: ios

I have seen Code snippets where people have written touchesBegan and touchesEnded in the View Controller of a view.

I am relatively new to iOS development and am unable to understand how is that possible.

Aren't these methods of UIView class that we override in our custom views.

and If its possible then If I call view's touches Event which version gets the priority ?
The one in the View controller or one in the View itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can easily look up in the documentation, the `touches...:withEvent:` family of methods is declared in the `UIResponder` class. Since both `UIView` and `UIViewController` inherit from `UIResponder`, both classes have access to the methods and can override them.

As to the question which implementation gets priority if both are implemented, that is defined by the responder chain. Touch events travel up the responder chain until they find an object that wants to handle the event. Since a view is placed before its view controller in the responder chain, the implementation in the view class would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The view controller has copies of these methods as well. It's for convenience so you don't have to create a custom UIView subclass just to handle touch interaction.

If both the view and the view controller implement these methods then they both get called when the user touches the screen, however I believe that the ones on the view get called first.

Note that as of iOS 3.2/4.0, UIGestureRecognizers are generally a much easier way to do most types of touch interaction. There's rarely any need to use touchesBegan and touchesEnded any more.